# listview showing database entries in eclipse but not in android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am new to Android development and also have recently shifted from eclipse to android studio. I am trying to make a reminder app. The problem arises that on entering the note in reminder, the database is created but not displayed on the screen, i.e. List view. Also I have checked that the database is created and all other things work fine except that my DB is not shown.

Here are the DBhelper class and ListView containing XML file:

P.S. if other java classes are needed...please let me know...

DBHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DataBase_NAME = "Reminder.db";
    public static final int DataBase_VERSION = 1;

    public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new
            SimpleDateFormat(RemindMe.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT);
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DataBase_NAME, null, DataBase_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Alarm.getSql());
        db.execSQL(AlarmTime.getSql());
        db.execSQL(AlarmMsg.getSql());
        Log.i(" this works","and this");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Alarm.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AlarmTime.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME);
        Log.i("at least this works","and this too");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void shred(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.delete(AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME, AlarmMsg.COL_STATUS+" = ?", new String[]
                {AlarmMsg.CANCELLED});
    }

    private final String populateSQL = Util.concat("SELECT ",
            "a."+Alarm.COL_FROMDATE+", ",
            "a."+Alarm.COL_TODATE+", ",
            "a."+Alarm.COL_RULE+", ",
            "a."+Alarm.COL_INTERVAL+", ",
            "at."+AlarmTime.COL_AT,
            " FROM "+Alarm.TABLE_NAME+" AS a",
            " JOIN "+AlarmTime.TABLE_NAME+" AS at",
            " ON a."+Alarm.COL_ID+" = at."+AlarmTime.COL_ALARMID,
            " WHERE a."+Alarm.COL_ID+" = ?");

    public void populate(long alarmId, SQLiteDatabase db) {



        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(alarmId)};
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(populateSQL, selectionArgs);


        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            AlarmMsg alarmMsg = new AlarmMsg();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                do {
                    Date fromDate = sdf.parse(c.getString(0)); //yyyy-M-d
                    cal.setTime(fromDate);

                    //at
                    String[] tokens = c.getString(4).split(":"); //hh:mm
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    String rule = c.getString(2); //every day month
                    String interval = c.getString(3); //mm hh dd MM yy

                    if (rule == null && interval == null) {//one time
                        alarmMsg.reset();
                        alarmMsg.setAlarmId(alarmId);
                        alarmMsg.setDateTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
                        if (alarmMsg.getDateTime() < now-Util.MIN)
                            alarmMsg.setStatus(AlarmMsg.EXPIRED);
                        alarmMsg.save(db);

                    } else {//repeating
                        if (rule != null) {
                            tokens = rule.split(" ");
                            interval = "0 0 1 0 0"; //date++;

                            //Day
                            if (!"0".equals(tokens[1])) {
                                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
                                        Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
                                interval = "0 0 7 0 0"; //week++;
                            }
                            //Every
                            if (!"0".equals(tokens[0]) && "0".equals(tokens[1]))
                            {
                                cal.set(Calendar.DATE,
                                        Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
                                interval = "0 0 0 1 0"; //month++;
                            }
                            //Month
                            if (!"0".equals(tokens[2])) {
                                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,
                                        Integer.parseInt(tokens[2])-1);
                                interval = "0 0 0 0 1"; //year++;
                            }

                            while(cal.getTime().before(fromDate)) {
                                nextDate(cal, interval);
                            }
                        }

                        Date toDate = sdf.parse(c.getString(1));
                        toDate.setHours(0);
                        toDate.setMinutes(0);
                        toDate.setSeconds(0);
                        toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+1);
                        while(cal.getTime().before(toDate)) {
                            alarmMsg.reset();
                            alarmMsg.setAlarmId(alarmId);
                            alarmMsg.setDateTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
                            if (alarmMsg.getDateTime() < now-Util.MIN)
                                alarmMsg.setStatus(AlarmMsg.EXPIRED);
                            alarmMsg.save(db);
                            nextDate(cal, interval);
                        }
                    }

                } while(c.moveToNext());

                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        c.close();
    }

    private void nextDate(Calendar cal, String interval) {
        String[] tokens = interval.split(" ");
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]));
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
    }

    private final String listSQL = Util.concat("SELECT ",
            "a."+Alarm.COL_NAME+", ",
            "am."+AlarmMsg.COL_ID+", ",
            "am."+AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME+", ",
            "am."+AlarmMsg.COL_STATUS,
            " FROM "+Alarm.TABLE_NAME+" AS a",
            " JOIN "+AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME+" AS am",
            " ON a."+Alarm.COL_ID+" = am."+AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID);

    /**
     * @param db
     * @param args {startTime, endTime}
     * @return cursor
     */
    public Cursor listNotifications(SQLiteDatabase db, String... args) {
        String selection = "am."+AlarmMsg.COL_STATUS+" != 
        '"+AlarmMsg.CANCELLED+"'";
        selection += (args!=null && args.length>0 && args[0]!=null) ? " AND 
        am."+AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME+" >= "+args[0] : "";
        selection += (args!=null && args.length>1 && args[1]!=null) ? " AND 
        am."+AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME+" <= "+args[1] : "";

        String sql = Util.concat(listSQL,
                " WHERE "+selection,
                " ORDER BY am."+AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME+" ASC");

        return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }

    public int cancelNotification(SQLiteDatabase db, long id, boolean isAlarmId)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(AlarmMsg.COL_STATUS, AlarmMsg.CANCELLED);

        return db.update(AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME,
                cv,
                (isAlarmId ? AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID : AlarmMsg.COL_ID)+" = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public int cancelNotification(SQLiteDatabase db, String startTime, String
            endTime) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(AlarmMsg.COL_STATUS, AlarmMsg.CANCELLED);
        return db.update(AlarmMsg.TABLE_NAME,
                cv,
                AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME+" >= ? AND "+AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME+" <= 
                        ?",
        new String[]{startTime, endTime});

    }


    public static final String getDateStr(int year, int month, int date) {
        return Util.concat(year, "-", month, "-", date);
    }

    public static final String getTimeStr(int hour, int minute) {
        return Util.concat(hour, ":", minute>9 ? "":"0", minute);
    }
}
```

XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f804fc" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:shadowColor="#333333"
        android:textColor="#d3e397"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Remind Me" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/preferences" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageButton1"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/range"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/range_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/line"
        android:dividerHeight="3dip"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:text="No data" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="3dip"
    android:background="#5c755e"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#3d4935"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="(c) appsrox.com" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

REMINDER CLASS:

```
  public class reminder extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private TextView headingText;
private Cursor c;
private TextView rangeText;
private ViewSwitcher vs;

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Typeface font;
private AlertDialog disclaimer;

public final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
public final Date dt = new Date();
private String[] monthArr;

private Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
private AlarmMsg alarmMsg = new AlarmMsg();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);
    findViews();
    db = RemindMe.db;
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-
    Semibold.ttf");
    headingText.setTypeface(font);
    monthArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner3_arr);

    int r = RemindMe.getDateRange();
    switch(r) {
        case 3: // Yearly
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);

        case 2: // Monthly
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        case 1: // Weekly
            if (r==1) cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

        case 0: // Daily
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    }

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong("cal", cal.getTimeInMillis());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(state.getLong("cal"));
}

private void findViews() {
    headingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading_tv);
    rangeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range_tv);
    vs = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.view_switcher);
  }

  private String getRangeStr() {
    int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    dt.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    switch(RemindMe.getDateRange()) {
        case 0: // Daily
            if (date==dt.getDate() && month==dt.getMonth() && 
 year==dt.getYear()+1900) return "Today";
            else return date+" "+monthArr[month+1];

        case 1: // Weekly
            return date+" "+monthArr[month+1] + move(+1) + " - " + 
 cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+" "+monthArr[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1] + move(-1);

        case 2: // Monthly
            return monthArr[month+1]+" "+year;

        case 3: // Yearly
            return year+"";
    }
    return null;
}

private Cursor createCursor() {
    if(c!=null){
     c = RemindMe.dbHelper.listNotifications(db, 
 cal.getTimeInMillis()+move(+1), cal.getTimeInMillis()+move(-1));
    startManagingCursor(c);
    return c;}
    else return null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.reminder_row,
            createCursor(),
            new String[]{Alarm.COL_NAME, AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME, 
    AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME, AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME, AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME},
            new int[]{R.id.msg_tv, R.id.year_tv, R.id.month_tv, 
    R.id.date_tv, R.id.time_tv});

    adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int 
    columnIndex) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.msg_tv) return false;

            TextView tv = (TextView)view;
            long time = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
            dt.setTime(time);
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.year_tv:
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(dt.getYear()+1900));
                    break;
                case R.id.month_tv:
                    tv.setText(monthArr[dt.getMonth()+1]);
                    break;
                case R.id.date_tv:
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(dt.getDate()));
                    break;
                case R.id.time_tv:
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    String txt = RemindMe.showRemainingTime() ? 
   Util.getRemainingTime(time, now) : Util.getActualTime(dt.getHours(), 
   dt.getMinutes());
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt)) txt = 
   Util.getActualTime(dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes());
                    tv.setText(txt);

                    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)tv.getParent();
                    TextView tv2 = (TextView) 
  parent.findViewById(R.id.msg_tv);
                    if (time < now) 
  tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#555555"));
                    else tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#587498"));
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    rangeText.setText(getRangeStr());
}

private String move(int step) {
    switch(RemindMe.getDateRange()) {
        case 0:
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1*step);
            break;
        case 1:
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7*step);
            break;
        case 2:
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1*step);
            break;
        case 3:
            cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1*step);
            break;
    }
    return "";
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings_Activity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddAlarmActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton3:
            move(-1);
            rangeText.setText(getRangeStr());

 ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).changeCursor(createCursor());
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton4:
            move(+1);
            rangeText.setText(getRangeStr());

  ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).changeCursor(createCursor());
            break;
    case R.id.toggleButton1:
        vs.showNext();
        break;*/
    }
}

 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo 
 menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == android.R.id.list) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reminder_context_menu, menu);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose an Option");
        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_menu_generic);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = 
 (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        alarmMsg.setId(info.id);
        alarmMsg.load(db);
        if (alarmMsg.getDateTime() < System.currentTimeMillis())
            menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_edit);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = 
  (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    boolean refresh = false;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_edit:
            alarmMsg.setId(info.id);
            alarmMsg.load(db);
            alarm.reset();
            alarm.setId(alarmMsg.getAlarmId());
            alarm.load(db);

            showDialog(R.id.menu_edit);
            break;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            RemindMe.dbHelper.cancelNotification(db, info.id, false);
            refresh = true;

            Intent cancelThis = new Intent(this, 
  reminder_alarm_service.class);
            cancelThis.putExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ID, String.valueOf(info.id));
            cancelThis.setAction(reminder_alarm_service.CANCEL);
            startService(cancelThis);
            break;

        case R.id.menu_delete_repeating:
            alarmMsg.setId(info.id);
            alarmMsg.load(db);
            RemindMe.dbHelper.cancelNotification(db, alarmMsg.getAlarmId(), 
 true);
            refresh = true;

            Intent cancelRepeating = new Intent(this, 
 reminder_alarm_service.class);
            cancelRepeating.putExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID, 
 String.valueOf(alarmMsg.getAlarmId()));
            cancelRepeating.setAction(reminder_alarm_service.CANCEL);
            startService(cancelRepeating);
            break;
    }

    if (refresh) {
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) 
  getListAdapter();
        adapter.getCursor().requery();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    openContextMenu(v);
}

     @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_edit:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Edit")
                    .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit, 
   null))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
  {
                            Dialog d = (Dialog) dialog;
                            EditText msgEdit = (EditText) 
 d.findViewById(R.id.msg_et);
                            CheckBox soundCb = (CheckBox) 
 d.findViewById(R.id.sound_cb);

                            alarm.setSound(soundCb.isChecked());
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msgEdit.getText())) {
                                alarm.setName(msgEdit.getText().toString());
                                alarm.persist(db);

                                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
    (SimpleCursorAdapter) getListAdapter();
                                adapter.getCursor().requery();
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(reminder.this, "Enter a 
  message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
 {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

  @Override
  protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_edit:
            EditText msgEdit = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.msg_et);
            CheckBox soundCb = (CheckBox) 
  dialog.findViewById(R.id.sound_cb);

            msgEdit.setText(alarm.getName());
            soundCb.setChecked(alarm.getSound());
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reminder_options_menu, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (getListAdapter().isEmpty()) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete_all).setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete_all).setEnabled(true);
    }
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_delete_all:
            String startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()+move(+1);
            String endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()+move(-1);
            RemindMe.dbHelper.cancelNotification(db, startTime, endTime);

            Intent cancelAll = new Intent(this, 
                                              reminder_alarm_service.class);
            cancelAll.putExtra(Alarm.COL_FROMDATE, startTime);
            cancelAll.putExtra(Alarm.COL_TODATE, endTime);
            cancelAll.setAction(reminder_alarm_service.CANCEL);
            startService(cancelAll);

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) 
            getListAdapter();
            adapter.getCursor().requery();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (disclaimer != null)
        disclaimer.dismiss();
    super.onDestroy();
}

 }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code from the activity that sets the ListView's adapter.

Comment: I highly doubt it has to deal with the transition from Eclipse to Android Studio

Comment: Also, include your code that creates the listview

Comment: Assuming that you are using the cursor from `listNotifications` to populate the ListView. Add a log, immediately after getting the cursor to display the count e.g. `Log.d("YOURTAG",Integer.toString(cursor.getCount());` run and confirm that you are getting data into the cursor. (i.e. Log should show a number other than 0, 0 will mean no data)

Comment: Do you mean that the data does not appear in Android Studio when you are editing your layout or that the data does not appear in your app when you run it on a device or emulator?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the data does not appear on app when run on emulator

Comment: @MikeT  can you explain a little bit regarding the code i have now added ....

Comment: @SuperStormer  i have added the code...

Comment: @user7786905 the code that you have added does not include the code from the activity that sets the ListView's adapter as requested. In short the issue is either that no data is being extracted from the database or that there are issues with the ListView, Determining which is important.

Comment: sorry @MikeT ,I thought  i had added it.....here is the Reminder activity class ....i have used ListActivity

Comment: @user7786905 OK add line `Log.d("TEST","Number of rows =" + Integer.toString(c,getCount()))` after `startManagingCursor(c);` in `createCursor()` method. Rerun and look at log and it should tell you how many rows in the cursor. If 0 then you need to find out why the cursor is empty, if not then issue is withing the adapter.

Comment: @MikeT thanx.....the problem was in the if condition of null cursor ....due to which the cursor was empty....

Comment: hey @MikeT now i am getting this exception :java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4a7d5588 .....is it one of the cons of using startManagingCursor() or can it be solved.....

Comment: @user7786905 I've never used startManagingCursor, so I'm not sure what the pros and cons are. I can say that I've had real issues not managing cursor myself. Although I believe that startManagingCursor may have been deprecated some API levels ago.